# Cant select which HDMI/DisplayPort monitor to output sound to

Tags: windows, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I've been banging my head against this issue ever since I got a third monitor. I have searched all over and can't seem to find anyone having the same issue.

Currently I resort to physically unplugging and replugging monitors every time I reboot my machine. I would like some sort of **software solution** to this (registry tweak, C#, PowerShell, whatever)

**My Setup**

- Windows 8.1 x64 (same issue on Windows 7)
- Radion HD 6970 (has three monitors connected one DP, one HDMI and one DVI)
- Same issue with AMD or Windows drivers installed
- Audio works on both the DP and and HDMI monitors (as expected, though windows defaults to the HDMI output which is not the one I want)

**Description of the issue**

- In Windows (7 and 8.1, not tested on others) I am only able to see one of my audio outputs from my graphics card at a time. Currently Windows defaults to the HDMI monitor and I cannot switch this from within Windows.
- No amount of messing with disabling monitors in display settings or uninstalling/reinstalling drivers so far has allowed me to switch the audio from my HDMI monitor to my DP monitor.
- I believe my video card can only output sound through one port at a time. This is fine, I just want the sound going to my DP monitor and NOT my HDMI monitor.
- The ONLY solution I've come up with is to **physically** unplug both HDMI and DP monitors, then plug them back in, DP first. After this process DisplayPort will then be an option to output sound to. This reverts to the HDMI monitor when I reboot. The DP monitor will only show up if I repeat this process again. Once I get the DP monitor to show up the HDMI monitor vanishes, and Windows all of a sudden, remembers that the DP monitor is set as the default audio device.

---

**Edit**

After trying everything @Tetsujin suggested in the comments below, the issue is still occurring (still, thanks for your help). I'm about to just start deleting all registry entries associated with the HDMI Audio device... If anyone else has any ideas please let me know, I beg.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the HDMI audio device from the sound control panel?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes, I've tried disabling it. the DP monitor still wont show up, the hell of it is, if I disable it and replugin the DP connector while leaving the HDMI plugged in, it still wont be recognized. I need to unplug Both, then plug them back in to get it to work.

Comment: I think it's to do with Windows only being able to recognise one source at once [or one analog, one digital, to be precise]. I wonder if it's possible to find it in Device Manager & disable it in the current profile? [It's not something I've done, so I'm guessing ]

Comment: @Tetsujin: Like I said. I have tried uninstalling/disabling (via th device manager and playback sound device panel) the HDMI monitor sound device entry. It gets removed from the list of options, but the DP monitor does not then show up as a valid option. If I do a scan for hardware changes after uninstalling the HDMI sound driver, it just shows right back up. :(

Comment: if you uninstall it, windows will pick it up again; that's not the same as disabling the device in the current profile, which [whether it *actually* helps or not] will prevent the driver from ever loading until you revert the setting manually. If it has no driver intentionally & *still* won't load the other driver instead, then you may be SOL, I'm afraid.

Comment: So you are saying to Disable the device in the device manager then reboot the machine? I believe I already tried this, though I'm not 100% sure. I'll do this when I get home and replace this comment with my findings.

Comment: Wish you luck. It ought to prevent it loading at all, so the other output would be 'first in the  queue'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22083/discussion-between-joseph-and-tetsujin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved my own issue and feel like and idiot.

I have three monitors, two of which have audio going through to them via DP or HDMI. I still can't change between the two without resorting to physically reconnecting them an the correct order. *However* I can just swap which cable goes to which monitor, therefore the audio still defaults to HDMI, *BUT* now goes to the correct monitor!

My father pointed this out to me today when I was visiting as the most obvious answer. I said that I had already tried swapping the connectors. I had already tried this but I thought I might have reconnected the DP connector first last time I tried, making the audio go to the DP connector and me thinking the solution didn't work.

So technically the question I asked is still not answered, but I no longer need an answer to my question as everything is working as I want now.